# Problem creating boot option for USB

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb

I have a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 13.10, but my ASUS g74 laptop doesn't have a boot option for USB.  I can create one, but it asks for a path.  The drive is the G drive, is it then /boot/grub?  what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu from a USB drive, you should:

1. Plug your USB Drive
2. Boot your computer

Then your computer should automatically show a welcome screen prompting you to choose your language and giving you the option to either `install Ubuntu` or `try Ubuntu from the USB`.

**ELSE** you might need to change the device from which the computer starts up to the USB.
**You can usually do this by watching for a message appearing when your computer starts to boot**:

- You should be invited to change the boot device. Once you’ve selected that option, follow the instructions on screen.
- Or you have to press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd> while your computer is starting up to change your boot device order.

Depending on your computer and how your USB key was formatted, you should see an entry for `removable drive` or `USB media`. Move this to the top of the list to force the computer to start from USB rather than the hard disk. Save your changes and continue.

<sub>*Info from [Install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)*</sub>